# how to compare two objects for equality by match each attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to match for equality in both the objects.
In the below objects, object 1 has null or " " value in the streetLines Array ,so i need to check for the same property in the other object whether it has value for the same.
How do i compare both the objects property by property.

Object 1:

```
address:Object
city:"QUEBEC"
Code:"CA"
postalCode:"G2E5H5"
stateCode:"PQ"
streetLines:Array[2]
0:"120 TERN CRT"
1:""
```

Object 2:

```
address:Object
city:"QUEBEC"
Code:"CA"
postalCode:"G2E5H5"
residential:false
stateCode:"PQ"
streetLines:Array[1]
0:"120 TERN CRT"
```

Comment: see if this solves your problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript

Comment: @Onera Does `JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2) ` meet your requirement?

Comment: we cannot compare directly like this it works only for  simple json without functions and order

Comment: @Frogatto  but in Objects  i have streelines array length different, so every time it shows false.

Comment: And Object 1 streetlines 1th index is not mandatory , we need to check only if it has some value in it